# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate creating new record

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

im trying to create a func to update my diary record using mongoose.

findOneAndUpdate requires a filter and doc params. Like this:

```
 const query = { name: req.body.name };
 const diary = { name: req.body.name, initDate: req.body.initDate,};
```

but when i run findOneAndUpdate, mongoose are creating a new document instead of changing the existing.

```
const diaryUpdated = await DiaryModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, diary, {
      upsert: true,
});
```

im doing something wrong?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the record with the given "name" (req.body.name) does not exist. Since upsert is enabled, Mongo will create a new document if it is not able to find an existing record with the queried name.

If that is the case, remove upsert or make it false. That might work.

You can find more on that here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert, i.e:

> An upsert behaves like a normal findOneAndUpdate() if it finds a
> document that matches filter. But, if no document matches filter,
> MongoDB will insert one by combining filter and update as shown below.